# USGS IMG File format specification

Tags: gis

Does anyone know where to get the file format spec for the USGS IMG files that they are using now for NED (DEM) data?  I would like to write code to read them directly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the "Grid FLoat" format is much more straightforward to use - I recommend this for "roll your own" terrain data coders!